# How to double click on an item from Calendar grid using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to select any specific grid from the calendar provided. I will attach the screenshot below. I need to double click on the grid and do some  functions  .

[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: can you suggest any methods for the same ?

Comment: Add piece of html for the calendar area or share the example calendar you have used

Comment: U can see i have added a link 'image'  along with my question .

Answer (score 0):

In java use actions class.

```
// init action
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
// find the element
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("random id");
// double click
action.doubleClick(element).build().perform();
```

In protractor

```
let grid = element(by.id('random id'));
browser.actions().doubleClick(grid).perform();
```

Comment: Can u identify the element for that grid ??

Comment: provide html sample.

Comment: Please view the image link along with the question .

Comment: Got the html sample ?